# Efficient SQL Query/Schema for a Leader Board

Tags: sql

I have written a stupid little game and want to have some kind of leader board website.

Usually leaderboards are limited to 10 or 20 top players, but I thought it would be nice if I could record, **for every player, their top score**. Then, I could always display their world-wide rank.

A simple schema such as:

```
create table leaderboard (
    userid varchar(128) not null,
    score real not null,
    when datetime not null
);
create index on leaderboard(userid);
```

Would store the minimal amount of information that I need - 1 entry per user with their best score.

My question revolves around how to efficiently determine someone's position on the leader board. The general idea is that I would want their position in the list returned by:

```
select userid from leaderboard order by score desc
```

But running this query and then linearly searching the list seems a bit ridiculous to me from a DB performance standpoint. Even so, I am having a hard time imagining a query/schema that would make it a quick operation.

Any ideas?

(I would prefer to keep the DB schema and query generic (not tied to a vendor). But, if one vendor makes this easy, I am happy to use either MS SQL or MySQL.

Comment: Put an index on score for performance and pk on userid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
select count(*)+1 as rank from leaderboard  
where score > (select score from leaderboard where userid = ?)
```

You'll also want an index on the score column.

Doing `count()+1` with `score > (...)` will give you accurate ranks even when multiple players have the same score; doing `count()` with `score >= (...)` will not.

Comment: Why is that though?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can use the [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102(SQL.90).aspx) function to return the rank for each user, based on their score

```
SELECT 
    userid,
    RANK() OVER 
    (ORDER BY score) AS rank
FROM leaderboard
```

If you had more than one type of 'game type', then you could include this in the Leaderboard table and use the `PARTITION BY` clause within the `RANK` function to determine ranking for each game type.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious option would be to create an index on "score", which is perfectly reasonable. (It sounds like you want to preserve two values - cumulative score and high-water score - or else I misunderstand?)

Unless you expect tens of thousands of users, even table scans shouldn't be a big problem on a table with that many records.

Comment: For clarification, I am only storing their best score.

Comment: OK, then an index on best score would be your best bet. If you SELECT COUNT(1) FROM leaderboard WHERE topscore >= (SELECT score ... etc.) will be efficient, since it will be resolvable by just scanning the index without reference to the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to query this:

```
select userid , max(score)
from leaderboard 
group by userid
order by max(score) desc
```

This returns the leaderboard with 1 entry for every user.

EDIT BELOW:
I see in the comment that you want to see the rank, not the score.
for this I don't know the ANSI SQL answer, but database specific:

In MySQL:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank
, t.userid 
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
 (select userid , score
from leaderboard 
order by score desc
) t;
```

In Oracle you can use the RANK statement.

Comment: This will give me their best score, but I'm really after their "rank" their distance from the "top".

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I'm glad to see that some databases have support for this.

Answer (score 1):

If this does not have to be real-time (for example if updating once a day is acceptable), add an additional "position" field and update it periodically using a query ordered by score.

Comment: Definitely a good option. I would like to avoid an offline process for now.

Answer (score 1):

In Sql server 2005, Rank() pretty much does the job for you. But if u have millions of records then ranking them real-time whenever the underlying stats change will be performance hog.

I tried to create a Indexed view on top of the select query... ( the voted answer in this thread ) but Sql 2005 would not let me create it cause u cannot use subqueries, self-reference in a indexed view.

So our workaround is to update the rank table nightly using Row() function. To avoid blocking while doing this update, we keep 2 copies of the ranking table one which is being updated and one which is being used in the application. We have a RankingView which points to the active ranking table at any given time.

I would like to know if there is a solution for real-time ranking update for really large tables ?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about the select "select count(*)+1 as rank from leaderboard
where score > (select score from leaderboard where userid = ?)"

Think of the the following situation:
Player 1, Score 100
Player 2, Score 100
Player 3, Score 50

Using that SQL the rank of player 3 would be 3, where  the correct answer should be 2, because Player 1 and Player 2 are tied in the first position. The count() aggregate function in that case consider 2 records with Score column > 50.

To handle this case I think the right option is to make a group by, so repeatable values of score will be handled as a single ranking position:

```
select score, count(*)+1 as rank from leaderboard  
group by score having (score) > (select score from leaderboard where userid = ?)
```